# Will a C# program for Windows run in Ubuntu under Mono without modification?

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, mono

i want to write a tcp server in c# under windows. can i run the same program or use the same code under mono without modification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to be careful with what you write. Mono isn't near 100% supporting .NET on Windows, but it's a very good start. a TCP server might be tricky because it tends to be the places that do hardware interaction (like IO) that have the most compatibility issues.

Mono has a free tool called MoMA that can analyze a .NET Application and tell you if it is going to have problems. You can download it here: http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA

Comment: If you ignore WCF, WPF, WF and the more esoteric parts of the framework like Enterprise Services, then Mono is very close to 100% .NET. TCP Server support is likely 100%

Comment: The older (but still effective) .NET Remoting is also working great. But yes, a simple TCP server will work with no changes.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest developing the application under Linux/Mono, then checking that it works on Windows. You're less likely to encounter issues that way.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking it should work if you aren't using OS specific actions. Miguel made a damn good job with Mono and you'll find it's very easy to work with.